# Apply VBA Macro Across Varying Cells?

Tags: vba, excel

[Image of the SpreadSheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZKlT.png) I am creating an Excel tracker for my work that determines when someone is within the secondary and primary zones of being promoted to the next rank. I started with Excel alone but that was too limited so I decided to try VBA which I have never used before. I currently have a script that reads what Rank the current individual is and then tells me the days they have from their Date of Rank, to the day they would be in the Primary or Secondary zones.

I can only do this for specific cells and I have to manually type in the date for their automatic promotion date. Is there a way to apply the same code along the whole sheet without having to manually change the cells. So if B2 contains the Rank of 'SPC' then F2 would have the days until the individual in that row has until they are in the Primary zone for 'SGT' and if B3 for example contains the Rank of 'PFC' then F3 would show the days until the individual is in the Primary zone for 'SPC' and so on.

```
Function Formula()
Workbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F2").Formula = "=DATEDIF(""2/24/2017"",Today(),""d"")"
End Function
```

It's something like that for the Macros. I'm not at work so I can't know for sure.

The Code for the sheet itself is something like

```
Sub Workbook_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
macroName As String
If macroName = "PFC" Then
Application.Run Formula()
ElseIf macroName = "SPC" Then
Application.Run Formula2()
EndIf
End Sub
```

I've forgotten what else is there but it only works for specifically Row 2 and I would like to apply it to each row accordingly. B3 & F3, B4 & F4 etc. Other things I think I can figure out on my own would be automatically adjusting the Primary Zone ending based on Date of Rank rather than making it manual.

Comment: Show some code!!! <3

Comment: Also you can look up the DateAdd function, which will help you automate the date differences. As long as you set up all your variables in the first place.

Comment: Assuming `Workbook_Change` is actually `Worksheet_Change`, and assuming you have set `Application.EnableEvents = False`, you could replace `Application.Run Formula()` with `Target.EntireRow.Range("F1").Value = #02/24/2017# - Date()` - that would cause column F in the row of the changed cell to be updated to be the number of days between 24 Feb and today.  (Obviously, the hard-coded date could be replaced by a date variable which has been calculated to be the automatic promotion date.)  Alternatively, you could use `Cells(Target.Row, "F").Value = #02/24/2017# - Date()`.

Comment: That definitely seems like it would work. I'll have to give it a shot when I go back in on Monday. Is there  a way I can store a date as a variable so I could read the Date of Rank in the "D" Column, add the necessary months to the automatic promotion date and store it to be referenced in that code? I have to make it as automated as possible so the people using it don't need to physically enter the code and change dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code you have shown, it would be easier to include the code from `Formula` into the `Worksheet_Change` event itself, e.g.

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim macroName As String
    macroName = "something"
    If macroName = "PFC" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Cells(Target.Row, "F").Formula = "=DATEDIF(""2/24/2017"",Today(),""d"")"
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    ElseIf macroName = "SPC" Then
        Application.Run Formula2()
    EndIf
End Sub
```

This does assume that the sheet on which the changed cell exists is Sheets("Sheet1").

Note that Application.EnableEvents has been disabled prior to making a change to the sheet.  This will stop Excel entering an infinite loop.

---

Alternatively, you could pass the changed cell as a parameter to `Formula`:

```
Function Formula(c As Range)
    Workbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(c.Row, "F").Formula = "=DATEDIF(""2/24/2017"",Today(),""d"")"
End Function

Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim macroName As String
    macroName = "something"
    If macroName = "PFC" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Formula Target
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    ElseIf macroName = "SPC" Then
        Formula2
    EndIf
End Sub
```

---

Or yet another way would be to just pass the row number of the changed cell as a parameter to `Formula`:

```
Function Formula(r As Long)
    Workbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, "F").Formula = "=DATEDIF(""2/24/2017"",Today(),""d"")"
End Function

Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim macroName As String
    macroName = "something"
    If macroName = "PFC" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Formula Target.Row
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    ElseIf macroName = "SPC" Then
        Formula2
    EndIf
End Sub
```

---

In order to calculate the correct date (and based on my first method of coding) you could do something like:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim macroName As String
    Dim mthsToAdd As Integer
    Dim apd As Date
    macroName = "something"
    If macroName = "PFC" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        mthsToAdd = 3
        'Note: The following formula won't correctly handle cases such as
        '      adding two months to 30 December 2016 (it will calculate
        '      2 March 2017 in that case, due to "30 February 2017" being
        '      treated as "2 days after 28 February 2017")
        Cells(Target.Row, "F").FormulaR1C1 = "=DATEDIF(Today(),DATE(YEAR(RC4),MONTH(RC4)+" & mthsToAdd & ",DAY(RC4)),""d"")"

        'or, if your formula doesn't need to allow for future changes to column D 
        apd = DateAdd("m", mthsToAdd, Cells(Target.Row, "D").Value)
        Cells(Target.Row, "F").FormulaR1C1 = "=DATEDIF(Today(),""" & Format(apd, "mm/dd/yyyy") & """,""d"")"

        'or, if you don't even need to allow for future changes to "Today"
        apd = DateAdd("m", mthsToAdd, Cells(Target.Row, "D").Value)
        Cells(Target.Row, "F").Value = apd - Date()

        Application.EnableEvents = True
    ElseIf macroName = "SPC" Then
        Application.Run Formula2()
    EndIf
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey there so at work now attempting to implement the suggestions you've made. There are no errors but nothing changes when the individuals rank has changed. I guess I should have also mentioned that the rank is located in Row "B". So basically when someone is promoted from PFC to SPC, their Primary and Secondary zone in Row "F" should shift accordingly. I tried changing the portion of 'macroName = "something"' to 'macroName = Cells(Target.Row, "B").Text' to see if that would lead to the result I'm looking for but no dice.

Comment: Okay so I was able to get it to work, the original code used If Target.Value = [Rank] and that works perfectly with your suggestions. The point I'm at now is that I need the value in Row "F" to essentially be entirely based on Rows "C" and "D" + a certain amount of months. So if the individuals Time in Service started 02/24/2015 they need 18 months TIS in order to be in the secondary zone for SPC. They would also need 6 Months Time in Grade from the date they became a PFC so 2/24/2016.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what you are after - is there any chance you can paste a screenshot of your worksheet into your question?  (Change any personal information such as names into generic values first.)  And then give some examples of what you want to appear in column F for various scenarios.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the Excel spreadsheet. What I would say I'm looking for is basically BASD represents the Start Date for the Individual. In order to be eligible for promotion to SGT they need to have 17 months Time in Service from that Date. They also would need 5 months from their Date of Rank which is DOR. So I need the Days to Secondary/ Primary to reflect the days they have until the reach the TIS and TIG required to be eligible.

Comment: Normally, the individual would always reach the TIS requirement prior to TIG due to the way promotions normally work. However special cases where an individual enters the service as a SPC would reach the 5 month TIG requirement well before he reached the TIS requirement necessary.

Comment: It **sounds** like you want to calculate `apd` as: `apd = DateAdd("m", 17, Cells(Target.Row, "D").Value)` and then next line being `If DateAdd("m", 5, Cells(Target.Row, "E").Value) > apd Then apd = DateAdd("m", 5, Cells(Target.Row, "E").Value)`.

Comment: That works exactly as I wanted! I appreciate it! I guess the last thing would be when the value that is made as a result of the formula is less than  Todays date it leaves a "#NUM!" value presumably because of it being a negative number. Is there a way for me to just zero it out? I don't think I need to see the negatives.

Comment: @GingerbreadPK - you can use the Excel function `IFERROR` to test for an error and set an alternative value.  For instance, `Cells(Target.Row, "F").FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(DATEDIF(Today(),""" & Format(apd, "mm/dd/yyyy") & """,""d""),0)"`

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you so much for all the help!